# Is there any way we can set grid-template-area to blank?

Tags: html, css, css-grid, bootstrap-grid

I am trying CSS GRID

```css
  .item1 { grid-area: header; }
      .item2 { grid-area: menu; }
      .item3 { grid-area: dashboard; }
      .item4 { grid-area: footer; }


      .grid-container {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-areas:
        'header header header header header header'
        'menu menu dashboard dashboard dashboard dashboard'
        'footer footer footer footer footer footer';
        grid-gap: 10px;
        background-color: black;
        padding: 10px;
      }
```

Is there any way in which we can set some grid-template-areas to blank?

Comment: https://www.w3.org/TR/css-grid-1/#grid-template-areas-null-cell-token ?

Comment: thanks @TemaniAfif that worked fine